# Behat: having method __toString() not implemented error

Tags: php, phpunit, tostring, behat

I have php 5.6.14.

Writing context for behat tests I saw an error:[image: error]

```
/** @When /^I want to see JS alert$/ */
public function iExecuteJs() {
    $this->webDriver()->executeScript("jsAlert()");
        if ($this->webDriver()->switchTo()->alert()->getText().contains("js")){
            echo "test passed";
        };

}
```

What should I do with it?

Thanks

Comment: `->getText().contains("js")` - shouldn't that dot be an arrow?

Comment: Tried it and got "method not found in class error.

Additionally, a bit modified the statement (nothing has changed, though):

        $element = $this->webDriver()->switchTo()->alert()->getText();

        if ($element->contains("js")){
            echo "test passed";
        }

Comment: You know, in PHP `.` is a string concatenation operator, it's not for method chaining like in C++ or JavaScript.

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk thanks, you've helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I changed the code like:

```
    $element = $this->webDriver()->switchTo()->alert()->getText();
        if ($element == "I am a JS Alert"){
           echo "correct js alert appeared";
        }
```